# Django queryset behind the scenes

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

**

### Difference between creating a foreign key for consistency and for joins

**

I am fine to use Foreignkey and Queryset API with Django.

I just want to understand little bit more deeply how it works behind the scenes.

In Django manual, it says

> a database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey. You can
>   disable this by setting db_index to False. You may want to avoid the
>   overhead of an index if you are creating a foreign key for consistency
>   rather than joins, or if you will be creating an alternative index
>   like a partial of multiple column index.

**creating for a foreign key for consistency rather than joins**

this part is confusing me.

I expected that you use Join keyword if you do query with Foreign key like below.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
vehicles 
INNER JOIN users ON vehicles.car_owner = users.user_id
```

For example,

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    address = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

class Comment(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKeyField(Place)
    content = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

if you use queryset like `Comment.objects.filter(place=1)`, i expected using Join Keyword in low level SQL command.

but, when I checked it by printing out queryset.query in console, it showed like below.

(I simplified with Model just to explains. below, it shows all attributes in my model. you can ignore attributes)

```
SELECT
 "bfm_comment"."id", "bfm_comment"."content", "bfm_comment"."user_id", "bfm_comment"."place_id", "bfm_comment"."created_at" 
FROM "bfm_comment" WHERE "bfm_comment"."place_id" = 1
```

**creating a foreign key for consistency vs creating a foreign key for joins**

simply, I thought if you use any queryset, it means using foreign key for joins. Because you can get parent's table data by `c = Comment.objects.get(id=1) c.place.name` easily. I thought it joins two tables behind scenes. But result of `Print(queryset.query)` didn't how Join Keyword but Find it by Where keyword.

---

### The way I understood from an answer

**Case 1:**

```
Comment.objects.filter(place=1)
```

result

```
SELECT 
"bfm_comment"."id", "bfm_comment"."content", "bfm_comment"."user_id", "bfm_comment"."place_id", "bfm_comment"."created_at" 
FROM "bfm_comment" 
WHERE "bfm_comment"."id" = 1
```

**Case 2:**

```
Comment.objects.filter(place__name="df")
```

result

```
SELECT "bfm_comment"."id", "bfm_comment"."content", "bfm_comment"."user_id", "bfm_comment"."place_id", "bfm_comment"."created_at" 
FROM "bfm_comment" INNER JOIN "bfm_place" ON ("bfm_comment"."place_id" = "bfm_place"."id") 
WHERE "bfm_place"."name" = df
```

**Case1** is searching rows which has comment.id column is 1 in just Comment table.
But in **Case 2**, it needs to know Place table's attribute 'name', so It has to use JOIN keyword to check values in column of Place table. **Right?**

**So Is it alright to think that I create a foreign key for joins if i use queryset like Case2 and that it is better to create index on the Foreign Key?**

for above question, I think I can take the answer from [Django Manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/)

> Consider adding indexes to fields that you frequently query using
>   filter(), exclude(), order_by(), etc. as indexes may help to speed up
>   lookups. Note that determining the best indexes is a complex
>   database-dependent topic that will depend on your particular
>   application. The overhead of maintaining an index may outweigh any
>   gains in query speed

In conclusion, it really depends on how my application work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute the following command the mystery will be revealed

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001
```

Take care to replace `myapp` with your app name (`bfm` I think) and 0001 with the actual migration where the Comment model is created.

The generated sql will reveal that the actual table is created with `place_id int` rather than a `place Place` that is because the RDBMS doesn't know anything about models, the models are only in the application level. It's the job of the django orm to fetch the data from the RDBMS and convert them into model instances. That's why you always get a `place` member in each of your `Comment` instances and that `place` member gives you access to the members of the related `Place` instance in turn.

So what happens when you do?

```
Comment.objects.filter(place=1)
```

Django is smart enough to know that you are referring to a place_id because 1 is obviously not an instance of a `Place`. But if you used a Place instance the result would be the same. So there is no join here. The above query would definitely benefit from having an index on the place_id, but it wouldn't benefit from having a foreign key constraint!! Only the Comment table is queried.

If you want a join, try this:

```
Comment.objects.filter(place__name='my home')
```

Queries of this nature with the `__` often result in joins, but sometimes it results in a sub query.

Comment: Thanks. your answer gave me some clue to understand. I added how I understood from your answer and relating questions in my question. Plz check it.

Comment: yes, you have understood my answer correctly. You would need a Foreignkey to be able to do place__name type queries. Please also note that I had to re-edit your question to keep it with the accepted style of question edits. Editing a question to add new questions to that question is frowned upon here. But obviously you are still new here so I am just telling you

Comment: Ok. I will check how you re-edit. Yes. I am quite new in here. so should I ask relating questions I asked with new question open? I knew that I should be one content for one questions. but I felt like it was questions which is included in this main question.

Comment: how about your answer for this? So Is it alright to think that I create a foreign key for joins if i use queryset like Case2 and that it is better to create index on the Foreign Key? I wondered this question in the first place because I wanted to make sure if it is better to create index on the Foreign key in that situation.

Comment: yes, better to leave the index in place. It's only when the table has millions of rows in it that you need to check if the inserts are slow. Then you can reconsider the index

Comment: I see. Thank you! (Shouldn't i say Thank you not only in my question content but also in any comment?)

Comment: don't worry too much about that (since you have accepted the answer.) when you say thank you in a comment without accepting the comment usually get's deleted by mods.

Answer (score -1):

Querysets are lazy.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
>   any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
>   and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
>   evaluated. Take a look at this example:

Comment: I think this is important aspect of QuerySet in Django. But It doesn't give an answer relating to my question. btw, Thanks.

Comment: Print the query set for the get method. Not the whole queryset. And you will see different sql output.

Comment: Well, btw I didn't click button 'this answer is not useful'. Even though your answer didn't give me right answer for my question but I appreciate you left comments for my question. I thought using queryset api in Django means using JOIN keyword in row level in database. But I was confused with result of raw SQL strings. Actually, I should do queryset to refer value in different table in FK relationship. Now It became clear with another answer. I just wanted to edit my question to share what I understood and check if it is correct.

Comment: Yeah no worries man not a problem. Your initial question seemed about "why are you getting a simple sql when Django orm allows relationship spanning" so answering that — it's because querysets are lazy. All good :)